# server buttons in iggrid column

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, ignite-ui

Is it possible to add asp.net server button as one of the columns in iggrid ?

OR

Is it possible to add HTML button to run at server in one of the columns in iggrid ?

The reason for this is : i need to call server methods from this button

My iggrid column formation is below

```
$(function () {
   var data = <%= GetAccountInformationJSON() %>;


    if ( data != '' )
    {
        $("#gridAccountInformation").igGrid({
            height: ((content_height - HeaderHeight) / 2) +"px",
            width: "100%",
            columns: [
                {headerText: "Account", key:"Account", dataType: "string"},
                {headerText: "Office", key:"Office", dataType: "string"},
                {headerText: "Balance", key:"Balance", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "Init Mrg", key:"InitMarginReq", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "OTE", key:"OpenTrdEqty", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "Total Eqty", key:"TotalEqty", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "Liq. Val", key:"LiquidatingVal", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "Ex/Def", key:"ExcessDeficit", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                {headerText: "Statement", key:"Statement", dataType: "string"}
            ]
            ,

            features:[
                 {
                     name: "Resizing",


                 }

            ],
            dataRendered: function (evt, ui) {

                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(1)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(2)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(3)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(4)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(5)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(6)").css("text-align", "center");
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(7)").css("text-align", "center");  
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(8)").css("text-align", "center");   
                ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(9)").css("text-align", "center");
            }
            ,
            dataSource: data //JSON Array defined above   

        });

        $("#gridAccountInformation").igGrid("option", "datasource", data);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `igGrid` is a client-side control and does not have server-side rendering like native Web Forms controls do. The `igGrid` HTML structure is rendered on the client and Web Forms controls are rendered on the server. This means that you cannot add a client-side template, for example, to render a server-side control inside an `igGrid` cell. Event if you render the server-side control on the server and then move it inside an `igGrid` cell on the client, you still won't get any server-side event argument related to the `igGrid`, like what row the button is located in, what column, what cell, etc.